# Как реализовать такое в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, связи, связывание-данных

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать. Есть 2 таблицы products(id, name, description) и images (id, id_product, name)

И я хочу сделать связь, что если удаляется продукт, то удаляются все изображения с этим продуктом, но в тоже время, чтобы можно было создать продукт БЕЗ изображений. Я пробовал так

```
ALTER TABLE tb_product
ADD CONSTRAINT tb_product_tb_image_id_product_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tb_image (id_product);
```

Вроде всё хорошо, но я не могу создать товар без изображений.

Comment: У вас ссылка не в том направлении, изображение должно ссылаться на продукт (т.е. констраинт добавляется в таблицу изображений) и его надо делать `ON DELETE CASCADE` что бы автоматом удалял изображение

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь с направлением констрейнта. И вообще непонятно, как Вы умудряетесь создать FK на явно НЕ-уникальный индекс...

Answer (score 2):

Это потому, что перепутали в направление связи. Констрейнт формируется в зависимой таблице. ( а как я понимаю картинка является зависимым объектом от продукта)

```
ALTER TABLE tb_images
ADD CONSTRAINT tb_image_tb_product_id_product_fk
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES tb_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

По идее такой констрейнт с каскадным удалением приведет к
1. созданию индекса на поле product_id в таблице image, что ускорит джойны
2. невозможности вставить image без продукта
3. к удалению связанных image при удалении продукта